# UML USE CASE understanding

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have a question:

how would a correct uml USE CASE look for a Step by Step application

for example: You chose first a catalog and then some chapters and after that you get some Data to work on.

so you would get *Choose catalog*, *choose chapter* and *work Data*
My question how should the association be between them?

Can anyone give me an example?

Thx in advance

Comment: You must use the **activity diagram** to show this flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cases describe the added value of the system under consideration. To achieve these goals you will have scenarios which of course have individual steps.

I recommend reading Bittner/Spence to get a good understanding of how UCs are synthesized.